Converting pandas dataframe to wiki markup table
I'm automating some data processing and creating jira tickets out of it.
Pandas does have to_html or to_csv or even to_markdown. But jira supports only wiki markup for creating a table.
e.g.
<!-- wiki markup -->
||header1||header2||header3||\r\n|cell 11|cell 12|cell 13|\r\n|cell 21|cell 22|cell 23|

will create



header1
header2
header3




cell 11
cell 12
cell 13


cell 21
cell 22
cell 23



Is there anyway to convert pandas dataframe to wiki markup table to be used in Jira?
I'm keeping df.iterrows as Last resort since iterating over dataframe is not a recommended solution as per answers in How can I iterate over rows in a Pandas DataFrame? Since my expected dataframe is small, iteration should be fine in my case. This question can be considered as more of a curiosity what can be done in case of larger dataframes.

I'd use another package, like tabulate. Something like tabulate(df, headers=df.columns), the supported formats can be found on the linked page.

@QuangHoang Thanks for tabulate library. After some initial search, found that it uses vectorized operations and faster than simple iteration. The conversation formats supported are also insane. Will do a performance test between both of them to have a better understanding.

Don't reinvent the wheel, tabulate supports a jira template:
from tabulate import tabulate

tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='jira', showindex=False)

Output:
'|| header1   || header2   || header3   ||\n| cell 11   | cell 12   | cell 13   |\n| cell 21   | cell 22   | cell 23   |'

If you really want the \r\n line separator:
tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='jira', showindex=False).replace('\n', '\r\n')


You can write a function that does this:
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "header1": ["cell 11", "cell 21"],
    "header2": ["cell 12", "cell 22"],
    "header3": ["cell 13", "cell 23"],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

def df_to_jira_wiki(df):
    headers = "||" + "||".join(df.columns) + "||"
    rows = "\r\n".join(["|" + "|".join(map(str, row)) + "|" for row in df.values])
    return headers + "\r\n" + rows

jira_markup = df_to_jira_wiki(df)
jira_markup


Which returns
'||header1||header2||header3||\r\n|cell 11|cell 12|cell 13|\r\n|cell 21|cell 22|cell 23|'

or
||header1||header2||header3||
|cell 11|cell 12|cell 13|
|cell 21|cell 22|cell 23|

in a printed version
